# Need help solving for a variable.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have: 
$$\sqrt{k} = \frac{\sqrt{k}}{2} + b$$

We need to solve for b, i have thought long and hard about how to get it to what the answer is $(\sqrt{k}/2)$, but my algebra is garbage. Would like some help on how to solve for b.

Thanks

Comment: Subtract $\sqrt k \over 2$ from both sides?

Answer (score 7):

Honestly I'm unsure if this is a troll question but in any case:

$\sqrt{k} = \frac{\sqrt{k}}{2} + b$

Subtract $\frac{\sqrt{k}}{2}$ from both sides so you get $\sqrt{k} - \frac{\sqrt{k}}{2} = b$

So that is $\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{k}}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{k}}{2}$

(I just added two fractions in the last step, got the common denominator, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to see how to approach this (assuming $k\ne 0$) is to divide both sides by $\sqrt{k}$ which yields
$$
1 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{k}},
$$
therefore,
$$
\frac{1}{2} = \frac{b}{\sqrt{k}}.
$$
Can you finish this?

Comment: Or subtract $\sqrt k \over 2$ from both sides and factor?

Comment: @AndrewLi yes but for a beginner with bad algebra skills it is easier to see it my way

Comment: How is this at all easier than subtraction?

Comment: @AndrewLi A person with primitive algebra skills may not recognize that $\sqrt{k} - \sqrt{k}/2 = \sqrt{k}/2$ so easily but will certainly see $1 - 1/2 = 1/2$